# Can't retrieve user data after successful Facebook authentication using AWS Cognito in Xamarin

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, authentication, xamarin, amazon-cognito

I need to access the email of the authenticated user that signed it through facebook with amazon-cognito in xamarin .

I have succeeded to sign in through facebook but I can't access the user email to save it in the database .

is there is any way to access the user data like the user email ?

here is the code I used :

```
callbackManager = CallbackManagerFactory.Create();

LoginManager.Instance.RegisterCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()
{
    HandleSuccess = loginResult =>
    {
        string userID;
        var accessToken = loginResult.AccessToken;
        userID = accessToken.UserId;
        //string user_name
        var permissions= accessToken.Permissions;
        App.OnFacebookAuthSuccess(accessToken.Token);
    },
    HandleCancel = () =>
    {
        App.OnFacebookAuthFailed();
    },
    HandleError = loginError =>
    {
        App.OnFacebookAuthFailed();
    }
});
```

public void OnClick(Android.Views.View v)
    {
        LoginManager.Instance.LogInWithReadPermissions(_activity, new List { "public_profile" , "email" });
    }
PS : in this line :

LoginManager.Instance.LogInWithReadPermissions(_activity, new List { "public_profile" , "email" });

he asks the user the permision to get his email , but how can I access this email in the code ?

Comment: After getting the access token you would require to make a call to facebook api to retrieve EmailId ... check this link for example .. (https://www.jimbobbennett.io/authenticating-your-xamarin-app-with-azure-and-facebook/)

Comment: I am glad that helped :)